# What does the comma operator do in Bash arithmetic?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

In Bash Manual, sec 6.5 Shell Arithmetic

```
expr1 , expr2
comma
```

What does the comma operator do?

Are `expr1` and `expr2` arithmetic expressions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`,` is a list operator.

The list of arithmetic expressions will be evaluated from left to right, the last expression result is the return value:

```
$ echo "$(( a=1, ++a, ++a ))"
3
```

---

The `,` list operator was added in bash-2.04-devel (along with pre/post increment/decrement operators).

You may want to read [`expr.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/expr.c) to see how other operators were implemented, and function [`expcomma()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/expr.c#n442) for `,` operator.

Comment: thanks. does the manual say that?

Comment: which reference can I find it?

Comment: @Tim, very interesting; I can't find it at all anywhere in the bash man page or anywhere in the POSIX specs!

Comment: How did you know? @C

Comment: @Tim: See the bash changelog, search for `comma operator`. The `bash` documentation is not clear about it.

Answer (score 8):

#### Bash

The comma operator is valid in bash (`LESS=+/'expr1 , expr2' man bash`):

> expr1 , expr2
> comma

And no other explanation of its use.
For that we have to read the ["C Language" description (where all this arithmetic operators were born)](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.17.html).

Example (as in the link above) (the second of which has the value 5):

```
$ echo "$(( (t=3, t+2) )) $t"
5 3
```

Or, simpler:

```
$ echo "$(( t=3, t+2 )) $t"
5 3
```

---

Yes each element separated by a comma [may be an expression](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.17.html):

```
1313    expression:
            assignment-expression
            expression , assignment-expression
```

#### POSIX

POSIX does **not** include a comma operator:
[Table: Selected ISO C Standard Operators and Control Flow Keywords](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tagtcjh_15)

Or just try:

```
$  dash -c 'echo $(( t=3,t+2 ))'
dash: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " t=3,t+2 "
$  bash -c 'echo $(( t=3,t+2 ))'
5
```

As IBM confirm in its [page for AIX and POSIX shell](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_arith_eval.htm) (emphasis mine):

> All of the integral operators, **other than** ..., and comma (,), are supported.

But, also in AIX, IBM claim support for comma operator [from the ksh93 shell at `/usr/bin/ksh93`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_enhanced.htm)

> More arithmetic operators are available, including the unary +, ++, --, and the ?: construct (for example, "x ? y : z"), as well as the , (comma) operator.

#### Conclusion:

```
dash, ksh   do not have a comma operator.
ksh93          may have a comma operator.
bash, zsh   do     have a comma operator.
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't `echo "$(( t=3, t+2 )) $t"` output  `5 3`?

Comment: A typo, check again :-)

Comment: What's the extra parentheses in the previous example for? Why are the results the same with and without them?

Comment: The same way as in school math: `(2+3)` is `5` as `((2+3))` is `5`, as `2+3` is also `5`. Additional parenthesis just help collect together some elements. They are discarded after use (if not needed to parse the equation).

Comment: @Tim A thanks, So many questions and not even **one** upvote? Shame on you.